# How to disconnect or close database connection from DB in php mysql in OOPS

Tags: php, mysql, database, oop

Consider 3 classes **DBCONNECT**, **book**, **new**

```
class dbconnect {
    protected $db_conn;
    public $db_user='xxxx';
    public $db_pass='xxxx';
    public $db_host='localhost';
    public $db_name='xxxx';

function connect() {
        try{
            $this->db_conn=new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name",$this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
            return $this->db_conn;
        }
        catch (Exception $e){
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}


include_once ( 'class.dbconn.php' );

class Book{
    public $link;

    public function __construct(){
        $db_conn=new dbconnect();
        $this->link = $db_conn->connect();
        return $this->link;
    }
}

class new{
include_once 'classes/class.book.php';
$book = new Book();
}
```

everything works fine there were no errors in my code but I have a doubt of closing the connection to my database. Is it mandatory to close a connection? If it's mandatory, then how do I close the connection and in which class I need to write the code?

Answer (score 0):

It's not mandatory to close the connection manually. PHP will handle that on it's own. If you want to manually close it you can use `$this->db_conn = null;`

```
public function disconnect() {
    $this->db_conn = null
}
```

If you want to be a perfectionist, you could also do this, although not necessary

```
public function __destruct() {
    $this->disconnect();
}
```

Comment: The database class that contains your database connection. I assume you are using your own database class because you use `$this->db_conn=new PDO(...)`

Comment: @user1887128 the dbconnect class probably, although it's usually not necessary if you're going to manage one or two connections, but if you're going to have a lot of connections, you will want to close them manually when they are not needed. Of course, the best practice is to always close a connection you won't use again.

Comment: Then i hope to add the fallowing code

public function __destruct()
 {
   $this->db_conn=null;
 }

Answer (score 0):

your new code

```
<?php
class dbconnect {
    protected $db_conn;
    public $db_user='xxxx';
    public $db_pass='xxxx';
    public $db_host='localhost';
    public $db_name='xxxx';

function connect() {
        try{
            $this->db_conn=new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name",$this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
            return $this->db_conn;
        }
        catch (Exception $e){
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

function disconnect()
    {
            try
            {
                $this->db_conn=null;
                return $this->db_conn;
            }
            catch (Exception $e){
                return $e->getMessage();
            }
            }
    }
}


include_once ( 'class.dbconn.php' );

class Book{
    public $link;

    public function __construct(){
        $db_conn=new dbconnect();
        $this->link = $db_conn->connect();
        return $this->link;
    }
}

class new{
include_once 'classes/class.book.php';
$book = new Book();

$close = new dbconnect();
// this will close connection
$close->disconnect();


}?>
```

one more thing is you can create constructor and destructor.